# Converting Custom WordPress Pages to Core PHP - Issue with case sensitive URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We're currently in the process of migrating custom WordPress pages to core PHP for our website. However, we've encountered an issue related to URL case sensitivity that we're struggling to resolve.

In our WordPress setup, URLs are case-insensitive, allowing both lowercase and uppercase variations to resolve to the same page. For example, `https://example.com/Explore` and `https://example.com/explore` both successfully load the "Explore" page. Another example is `https://example.com/Game-details/game/123456`. `Game-details` is PHP page and `12345` is value for the key `game` field.

However, after converting these pages to core PHP and deploying them, we've noticed that only lowercase URLs work as expected. Uppercase URLs result in 404 errors.

We've attempted various solutions in our .htaccess file to enforce lowercase URLs, such as using RewriteMap and RewriteRules. While these solutions successfully redirect uppercase URLs to lowercase, they unfortunately affect other files like images and JavaScript, leading to unintended issues.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${tolower:$1} [R=301,L]
```

But it converts image path and that shows 404 for the images.

We're seeking advice on how to properly handle URL case sensitivity in a core PHP environment without causing conflicts with other files or disrupting existing functionality. Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have a wild mix of upper and lower case in your server side file system. A typical mistake people make when being used to MS-Window's case insensitive file system once they use typically Linux based web servers that use Unix typical case sensitive file systems. Can't you simply convert the file and folder names to all lower case? Or any other clear scheme like lowerCamelCase? Otherwise you need to implement specific rules that are able to match the case labyrinth you actually have.

Comment: the files are in small case only but I want to let user access the pages either by entering https://example.com/Game-details or entering https://example.com/game-details like wordpress does. Please note that we are not using folder we just removed .php extension from link in htaccess file.

Comment: "we just removed .php extension from link in htaccess file." - please show your complete `.htaccess` file. You need to convert only the URLs that would map to `.php` files to lowercase (or exclude your static assets from the rule). How are you handling the "fields", eg. `/Game-details/game/123456`? "we've noticed that only lowercase URLs work" - presumably that's because you converted the directories/files to lowercase? Unless your WordPress site was _redirecting_ `/Game-details` to lowercase (or vice versa) then that was potentially a duplicate content issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${tolower:$1} [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> we just removed .php extension from link in htaccess file.

Since this also converts image paths and other static assets (JavaScript, CSS, etc.) that are intentionally mixed case you either need to only apply this rule to URLs that ultimately map to `.php` files. Or exclude URLs that map to static assets... either by excluding URLs that end in a particular file extension (preferable) or URLs that already map to files.

For example:

```
# Exclude static assets from lowercase conversion
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|gif|jpg|webp)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) /${tolower:$1} [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Use a 302 (temp) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

If all your static assets are in a subdirectory then you could just exclude that subdirectory instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/ [NC]
:
```